# uploading of files and images

Tags: java, file-upload

I have to upload images and pdf files from client side to server side, using  browsing of file. I m using jboss,Tomcat and Apolloclient. How can i do that?? Which function and library have to refer???

Comment: Another file-upload question asked by you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038798/uploading-of-pdf-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Is what you want?](http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/file_upload/Sinle_upload.xhtml.shtml)
[And another link on that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Apache's common's file upload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/),  [here](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html) is quick start up guide

Answer (score 0):

I offer for is ZUpload good applet product free and very useful! it will help you to upload files to ftp server.