# Error in processing uploaded file

Tags: java, jsp

I'm trying to read an uploaded file and save it in DB using JSP.

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.sql.*,java.util.*,java.text.*,java.text.SimpleDateFormat" %>
<html>


<%
int val =0;
String contentType = request.getContentType();

if ((contentType != null) && (contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data") >= 0)) {
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream());

int formDataLength = request.getContentLength();
byte dataBytes[] = new byte[formDataLength];
int byteRead = 0;
int totalBytesRead = 0;

while (totalBytesRead < formDataLength) {
byteRead = in.read(dataBytes, totalBytesRead, formDataLength);
totalBytesRead += byteRead;
}

String file = new String(dataBytes);
String saveFile = file.substring(file.indexOf("filename=\"") + 10);
System.out.println("saveFile=" + saveFile);

saveFile = saveFile.substring(saveFile.lastIndexOf("\\")+ 1,saveFile.indexOf("\""));
System.out.println("saveFile" + saveFile);

saveFile = file.substring(file.indexOf("filename=\"") + 10);
saveFile = saveFile.substring(0, saveFile.indexOf("\n"));
saveFile = saveFile.substring(saveFile.lastIndexOf("\\")+ 1,saveFile.indexOf("\""));

int lastIndex = contentType.lastIndexOf("=");
String boundary = contentType.substring(lastIndex + 1,contentType.length());
int pos;

pos = file.indexOf("filename=\"");
pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;

int boundaryLocation = file.indexOf(boundary, pos) - 4;
int startPos = ((file.substring(0, pos)).getBytes()).length;
int endPos = ((file.substring(0, boundaryLocation)).getBytes()).length;

FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(saveFile);
fileOut.write(dataBytes, startPos, (endPos - startPos));
%>


<%
Connection con=null;
PreparedStatement pstatement = null;
String line = null;
String value=null;






try
{
StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(saveFile));

while (( line = input.readLine()) != null){
contents.append(line);

}


value = contents.toString();
System.out.println("Value:"+value);

Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://W2K8SERVER:1433/career","sa","Alpha#123" );

java.util.Date now = new java.util.Date();
String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
String strDateNew = sdf.format(now) ;



String queryString = "INSERT INTO file_tbl set file_data='"+value+"',file_date='"+strDateNew+"'";

//out.println(queryString);

pstatement=con.prepareStatement(queryString);

val = pstatement.executeUpdate();

if(val>0)
{
%>
<br><br>
<b>File <% out.println(saveFile); %> has been uploaded and inserted into Database at <%=strDateNew%>.</b>
<%
}


}
catch(Exception e)
{}
}
%>
</html>
```

However, I get the following error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /sendfile.jsp at line 26
->root cause 
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -53652
```

How is this caused and how can I solve this?

Comment: Please put roseindia.net in your blacklist of sites. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038798/uploading-of-pdf-file/5041420#5041420

Comment: For future reference, you can improve readability of code blocks by prepending each line of code with four spaces - this will separate it out as a code block and give you syntax highlighting.

Comment: I've merged your two accounts together. Please take the next few days to review the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).  I'd also suggest you read [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/) for hints on how to ask better questions.

Answer (score 0):

There's a large number of `String.IndexOf()` calls in there without any kind of exception handling for the case when the parameter you pass to it is not found within the string, which would return a -1 and cause an exception of you were nesting it inside another call, say to `Substring`, that expected a non-negative integer for a parameter.  I'm guessing that's where your `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

what the following code will work.......

```
saveFile = file.substring(file.indexOf("filename=\"") + 10);
saveFile = saveFile.substring(0, saveFile.indexOf("\n"));
saveFile = saveFile.substring(saveFile.lastIndexOf("\\")+ 1,saveFile.indexOf("\""));
```

Comment: You may want to be a little more clear on your answer, provide some detail.