# Uploading an image with JSP in Tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, file-upload

I am having trouble uploading an image with JSP in Tomcat.
I had some old code, but the packages seem to be deprecated now or whatever.

Is there some tutorial for that.

Comment: Have you [searched for answers before](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+file+upload+servlet+jsp)? Now would be a good time to go through those links. This has been whipped to death on the java and servlet tags.

Comment: http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/upload-insert-csv.shtml

Comment: Yes, there probably is a tutorial for that.

Comment: I have searched. I just can't make them work. For example import org.apache.commons.fileupload gives that package does not exists. I have netbeans 7 and tomcat 7.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upload files in JSP/Servlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet)

Comment: @Srikanth: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038798/uploading-of-pdf-file/5041420#5041420

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it with FileUpload in Apache Common... There user guide is a good place to start. http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html

But there is an easy way to upload files to the server side. You can download the code from here. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22048850/com.rar

```
try {
           com.tutetree.upload.manager.UploadManager up  = new com.tutetree.upload.manager.UploadManager(request);
           out.print(new String(up.getDataBytes()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
```

But if you want additional functions the best option is to use the FileUpload in Apache Common

Hope this helps ^^