# Google cloud Sql - Insert image failed

Tags: java, jsp, google-cloud-sql

I was following [JSP Insert Image][1] to insert  image on Google Cloud Sql using jsp, but it failed. I got `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.io.FileOutputStream is a restricted class.Please see the Google App Engine developer's guide for more details.`

Below is my code:

Page.JSP

```
<%@ page language="java" %>
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>Display file upload form to the user.</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY> <FORM ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" ACTION="upload.jsp" METHOD=POST>
<br><br><br>
<center>
<table border="0" bgcolor=#ccFDDEE>
<tr>
<center>
<td colspan="2" align="center"><B>UPLOAD THE FILE IN JSP PAGE</B><center></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Choose the file To Upload:</b></td>
<td><INPUT NAME="file" TYPE="file"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Send File"> </td>
</tr>
<table>
</center>
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Upload.jsp

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.zip.*"%>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.AppEngineDriver" %>
<%
String saveFile="";
String contentType = request.getContentType();
if((contentType != null)&&(contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data") >= 0)){
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream());
int formDataLength = request.getContentLength();
byte dataBytes[] = new byte[formDataLength];
int byteRead = 0;
int totalBytesRead = 0;
while(totalBytesRead < formDataLength){
byteRead = in.read(dataBytes, totalBytesRead,formDataLength);
totalBytesRead += byteRead;
}
String file = new String(dataBytes);
saveFile = file.substring(file.indexOf("filename=\"") + 10);
saveFile = saveFile.substring(0, saveFile.indexOf("\n"));
saveFile = saveFile.substring(saveFile.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1,saveFile.indexOf("\""));
int lastIndex = contentType.lastIndexOf("=");
String boundary = contentType.substring(lastIndex + 1,contentType.length());
int pos;
pos = file.indexOf("filename=\"");
pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
int boundaryLocation = file.indexOf(boundary, pos) - 4;
int startPos = ((file.substring(0, pos)).getBytes()).length;
int endPos = ((file.substring(0, boundaryLocation)).getBytes()).length;
File ff = new File(saveFile);
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(ff);
fileOut.write(dataBytes, startPos, (endPos - startPos));
fileOut.flush();
fileOut.close();
%><Br><table border="2"><tr><td><b>You have successfully upload the file:</b>
<% out.println(saveFile);%></td></tr></table>
<%

ResultSet rs = null;
PreparedStatement psmnt = null;
FileInputStream fis;
try{
Connection c = null;
c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:google:rdbms://smartposterdb:uploadimagedb/guestbook");
DriverManager.registerDriver(new AppEngineDriver());
File f = new File(saveFile);
psmnt = c.prepareStatement("insert into photo(image) values(?)");
fis = new FileInputStream(f);
psmnt.setBinaryStream(1, (InputStream)fis, (int)(f.length()));
int s = psmnt.executeUpdate();
if(s>0){
System.out.println("Uploaded successfully !");
}
else{
System.out.println("Error!");
}
}
catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}
%>



  [1]: http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/HTML/18225-Adding-image-to-database-through-jsp-or-HTML-page-while-adding-only-image-should-show-.html
```

Comment: Please do not read roseindia.net "tutorials". They are overloaded with **bad practices**. The problems with this particular piece of code are outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038798/uploading-of-pdf-file/5041420#5041420

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, firstly, Google App Engine has a set of restrictions around allowable operations on the filesystem. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Engine#Restrictions

Secondly, given this, why don't you just write your file as a byte array into a SQL BLOB/CLOB object instead (I'm assuming these are available on Google Cloud SQL)? You'll probably need to base64-encode/decode it when reading to and writing from SQL, though